# How to get controls ID's on Pageload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    Dim lbl_Date As New Label
    Dim i as int16
    i = 20
    While (i < i + 1)
       lbl_Date = TryCast(Page.FindControl("lbl_Date" + i.ToString), Label)
       lbl_Date = "Value"
   i = i + 1
   End While
End Sub
```

This is returning Nothing in `lbl_Date` variable. If i don't use this in `Page_Load`, it works just fine.  Only in `Page_Load` it doesn't work. Any **Explanation** :::: Well what i am trying to do here is . i have 100 label name are lable1 to lable100. I can do like label1 =Value and label2 =Value and so on but i am trying to put in loop so i have less code. just for the Info... **This code work but not in Page_Load , I am thinking every one looking to the code but this has to do with page life cycle**

Comment: Are you using a MasterPage? Where are the controls on the page? Why are you appending 1 to the ID? Do you want the ID or the control?

Comment: Be more specific with your question. Try to explain the comment of @Tim and please stop think about -1.

Comment: He(or she) probably will remove the downvote if you provide the missing informations.

Comment: This is so not ok , if someone new asking a question don't you guys can it easy.... plus what's wrong with me question????

Comment: Please note this is not a discussion forum, is a place to answer your doubts. Please be more specific and they will remove downvotes.

Comment: This is a simple/single/one/just a single page no master or child  page of ASP.net ..... and my question is simple is as well . How i get my control's ID's such AS label , textbox etc , on Page load .

Comment: @NaveedAnjum: `Label`, `TextBox` etc. are not ID's but control types. So again, do you need the ID's(If not you, then who should know?), the ClientID's(which are rendered in the html) or the reference to the controls themself?

Comment: If you are developing within Visual Studio, they will be automatically displayed at the code typing (Intellisense).

Comment: Gustavo.... Let me go back and explain again. I am using VS 2008 . I have a .aspx page, only one page in my project so far. i hope i am clear so far. if you look at my code , i am trying to find my control. Caz i have lable like name lbl_date1 and lbl_date2 and lbl_date3 and so on. so what i am trying to do is (i = 1
    lbl_Date = TryCast(Page.FindControl("lbl_Date" + i.ToString), Label)
) so this way less code

Comment: You're welcome, but please remain focused at the question and we'll try to easy solve your problem together.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter , I think you didn't look at my code with keen eyes...Dim lbl_Date As New Label     Dim i As Int16    i = 1  While (i < i + 1)              lbl_Date = TryCast(Page.FindControl("lbl_Date" + i.ToString), Label)
end while

Comment: @NaveedAnjum: Please edit your question with new informations so that all people will see it at the first place. The question will also get more attention if you edit it(bump to the top).

Comment: Tim and Gustavo are trying to *help* you, but you are focusing on being downvoted with a poorly constructed question.  You've been on SO for a while and asked several questions, so you should already know how to ask a good question and what the downvotes mean.  If you get downvotes, you should update your question with more information.  If somebody asks you a question in a comment, it probably means that your question wasn't clear *to them*.  Put forth some of your own effort and more people will be willing to help you.

Comment: @NaveedAnjum: Yes, but the edited code is an infinite loop since `i` will always be lower than `i+1`.

Comment: i am trying to put as much as information out there. i think i left if out i = i+1 . please check my question again. i tried to update and provide more information.

Comment: I have deleted my latest answer. I'm too confused about what we are trying to solve right now. Try to take of the **NEW** statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<asp:content runat="server" id="leftcontent" contentplaceholderid="LeftSidePanel" xmlns:asp="#unknown"> 
<div id="mydiv" runat="server"> 
<asp:linkbutton id="Lnk_Heading1" runat="server"> </asp:linkbutton>
<asp:label id="lbl_Date1" runat="server"> </asp:label>
<asp:label id="lbl_Detail1" runat="server"> </asp:label>
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Button" /> 
</div> 
</asp:content>

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
Dim lbl_Date As New Label 
Dim i as int16 i = 20 
While (i &lt; i + 1) lbl_Date = TryCast(Mydiv.FindControl("lbl_Date" + i.ToString), Label) 
lbl_Date = "Value" 
i = i + 1 
End While 
End Sub
```

Problem was , I didn't Used DIV in my aspx page . When i put my code in div and use the reference of the div in codebehind then it work.